# Sticky header with transition animation

Tags: jquery, css, menu, sticky

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav').data('size', 'big');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#nav').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#nav').data('size', 'small');
            $('#nav').stop().addClass('nav-min');
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#nav').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#nav').data('size', 'big');
            $('#nav').stop().removeClass('nav-min');
        }
    }
});
```

.. works perfectly, however the menu jumps from normal to min, is it possible to somehow animate it so the transition looks smooth?

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably have to use animate() rather than (or in conjunction with) changing classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate *and* change classes...

```
$('#nav').stop().animate({...}, 999, function() {
    $('#nav').addClass('nav-min');
}):
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's nothing to animate. adding the class does a lot of things, those I'd like to animate automatically during the transition.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You have to animate the things that your class applies. If you then no longer have a use for the class, discard it. If you use it as a selector for other operations, say, keep it.

Comment: The class reduces the height of the nav, changed the background and hides and certain elements. I can't do all that through animate()

Comment: True, which is why we add the class after the height and background animations. You could also do those other things with jQuery.

Comment: And technically you can do all that through animate. :-)